# Unable to instantiate decoder OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome on react-native-video

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am building a react-native app for android and I am receiving an error when trying to play different videos using react-native-video.
The error says:

```
[errorException] => com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [3840, 2160, -1.0], [-1, -1])
[errorString] => Unable to instantiate decoder OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome
```

I have found [this](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2116) suggestion to change the decoder, but in JS it seems to be impossible. Is there any way to accomplish this? Or would you suggest another native-video player?

Comment: Did you found any solution/workaround? @

Comment: I am also facing same issue? any solution found?